# Reinstalling numpy under ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, numpy

Somehow I managed to break a working `numpy` library (I tried to install some optimization libraries).
If I run `import numpy` in ipython then I get `ImportError: libblas.so.3gf: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS32`.

Reinstallation of numpy does not help (using `sudo-apt get remove/install`).

I see that the problem is libblas is 32bit version. I did not find 64 version in synaptic package manager.

Another confusing part is, ipython says that error is in

```
 `/home/andrey/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/linalg/linalg.py`
```

but when I delete numpy, this folder still exists.

Do you know how can I fix it?

Comment: Is your system 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: How did you manage to install a 32-bit libblas and at the same time not find the 64bit one?

Comment: The folder `/home/andrey/.local/lib/python2.7` was probably created when you manually installed some package instead of using the Ubuntu package management software (maybe you tried to install `numpy` manually). It was not created while installing `numpy` using `synaptic`. You can consider renaming/removing/backing-up the folder `/home/andrey/.local/lib/python2.7` and trying again. Meanwhile, it will help if you post information about the procedure you followed to reach this stage and complete error messages as well.

Answer (score 0):

`~/.local/lib/python2.7` is the per-user installation directory, of course you cannot uninstall numpy from there using `apt-get`. As numpy there is apparently 64bit, it requires 64bit libs so you need to install 64bit libblas on your system.